# rails dynamic dropdown error with application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

i am still new to rails and i need your help. I have a little ticketsystem. I want to show a dropdown menu in my navbar (bootstrap 3) with my different tags. This is working for the index of my tickets.

Here is a part of my application.html.erb

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tags <b class="caret">    </b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
        <% ticket.tags.each do |tag| %>
      <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag) %>
```

But when no other site is working when I add the above code to my navbar. For example when I want to open a tag i get the following error. (When i remove the above code, everything is fine.

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #32): app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #32 raised:

```
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tags <b class="caret"></b></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li>
           <% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to access `@tickets` at the application layout level(Master layout).

If you want to then, you need to set the value of `@tickets` in `ApplicationController`.
You are getting error as its currently set to nil.

You can update `ApplicationController` as follows to set it:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_tickets

  private
  def set_tickets
    @tickets = Ticket.all ## Assuming that you want all tickets from model Ticket
  end

end
```

`@tickets= Ticket.all` change the query as per your requirement.